# Facebook share button Wordpress Issue

Tags: php, wordpress, facebook, facebook-graph-api

When I click the 'Facebook' share button, a popup window appears showing "Just another wordPress Site". What might be the reason?

Comment: 'cntechserv' dot com is website name.

Answer (score 0):

its in your page head.  Its the default for any wordpress site you need to go into your admin panel under general settings and change this under "tagline" for your website

Comment: Adding on, if you still see "Just another WordPress Site" on facebook, you will have to request a manual scrape of your page using the facebook Debugger 'lint' tool found here: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/ enter the URL of your website and click debug, then proceed to click 'Fetch new scrape information'.

Comment: thanks. but i know and remove tagline 3 days before. but still remain issue. I think it is because of google crawl.

Comment: You can always manually submit sites or pages to be crawled or re-crawled by googlebot via Google's Webmaster tools! This will speed up the update!